# Mocking provider, injecting stuff

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking

*I have a somewhat complicated scenario here, I'll try my best to explain it, sorry if it's feels confusing.*

Say, I have a contrived provider sitting in  module aptly named `core`, let's call it `actionProvider`, it can register actions and then later invoke them.
And I use it like this:

```
 // registering an action in m1 module
 angular.module('m1').config((actionProvider)=> {

     actionProvider.reg('myAction', { $fn: myActionFn });

     myActionFn.$inject = ['$modal'];  

     function myActionFn($modal) {
         $modal.open()    // when action invoked it opens a modal dialog 
     } 
 })


// now somewhere else I invoke that previously registered action 
angular.module('m2').controller('myCtrl', (action)=> {
  action.invoke('myAction');    // and that calls $fn with $modal.open()
})
```

And this works perfectly. Now, let's say I have to test `actionProvider` in a module that has no access to source code of actionProvider. Means I completely need to mock it.
Ok. Let's try doing this:

```
 angular.module('core', []).provider('action', function() {
     let self = this;
     self.actions = [];

     self.$get = ()=> { return self }; // essential function that every provider has

     // registering action just pushes it into the array of actions,
     // remember this is a fake provider
     self.reg = (action)=> {
        self.actions.push(action) 
     };

     // yet even though it's a fake it still needs to be able to invoke actions
     self.invoke = (actionName) {
         // so here I need to find specified action in the array and invoke it
     };
})
```

Finding the right action in `self.actions` is easy. But how do I invoke its `$fn` correctly? How do I tell injector to find all the objects that's been injected (in the case of `myAction` it would be `$modal` service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding what's injected into `myActionFn` is easy, you just need to inspect function's `$inject` property.

Next step is to simply invoke the function, passing into it what needs to be injected.

Using `Function.prototype.apply` in this case won't help, since we need to use angular's $injector. Creating an instance with `angular.injector()` wouldn't work either, because we need to use right instance of the injector.

The trick is to use `angular.mock.injector` to grab current injector instance.

so our `invoke` function should look like this:

```
 self.invoke = (actionName) {
     // instead of array it's probably better to use an object map for `actions` 
     let action = actions[actionName]; 

     inject(($injector)=> {
         $injector.invoke(action.$fn);
     })
 };
```